# PUBSUB push subscription(cloud run endpoint) acknowledging to avoid retries

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-run

I have a cloud run endpoint that gets triggered by a push type pubsub subscription and it recives the user specified message thorugh publsiher,I am trying to get the message acknowledged by the acknowldgement time but the cloud run endpoint is getting triggered multiple times ,not sure if my message is getting acknowldged or not.I want to check what is the process to make sure the message gets acknolwedged with status 200ok response to pubsub in python so that there will not be any retires after one successful attempt.

```
try:
    return Response("Processing completed", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"###:EX: Error processing message: {ex}")
    return Response("Error processing message", status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)                   I tried the above code block but it isnt making any response.
```

Comment: Do you have error trace (`###:EX: Error processing message`) in your logs?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere there are no errors but my cloud run keeps on running and does not see any acknowledgement happening at push subscription

Comment: So, can you add a print in the try section. To be sure that your code is correctly invoked.

Comment: Is there a global loadbalancer involved? A couple of days ago I forgot to add the backend to the load balancer and had a similar result

Comment: I don't have a load balancer ,I am trying to trigger a cloudrun endpoint with push subscription and acknowledge the message I received and make sure that message is not redelivered again

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i have added the print statements  and i am gettinge the pubsub message id through post api request Headers ,how could i make sure the message ID is acknowledged now and cloud run does not get rerun agian.

Comment: If you see only once the message ID, it means your message is acked.